# GStreamer Xcode 10 gst.h not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gstreamer, xcode10

I just upgraded to Xcode Version 10.0 (10A255) and my project stopped working because it can't find gst.h.

I have gst_ios_init.h included in the bridging header and `#include <gst/gst.h>` in it. After the Xcode update the project won't compile anymore with the error:

> 'gst/gst.h' file not found.

It has worked before, now it suddenly fails.

I have the framework included and the Framework Search Path and Header Search.

Comment: I think thats a known issue. All the GStreamer include files include their files with "include.h" and or <include.h> and one of them is for system libs and one for private ones. With XCode 10 this is now a hard error and GStreamer won_t work anymore. I don't have an easy fix though. But at least you know where to look at.

Answer (score 2):

I got my app running today with XCode Version 10.1 (10B61) thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443665/gstreamer-xcode-10-1-gst-gst-h-not-found) and [this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero/issues/81).

What I did:

1. Just to be sure, I deleted the previous installation of GStreamer (folder `/Library/Developer/GStreamer`). Also removed the GStreamer framework from my project. (Right click `Frameworks/GStreamer.framework` -> `Delete` -> `Remove reference`)
2. Installed GStreamer 1.14.4. You can get it from here: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/ios/1.14.4/
3. Grab the `GStreamer.framework` from `/Library/Developer/GStreamer/iPhone.sdk` and drop it again in the `Frameworks` folder of the project. I did not check the `Copy files if necessary` option.
4. Changed the search paths in my TARGET to:

**Framework search path:** 
`"$(HOME)/Library/Developer/GStreamer/iPhone.sdk"`

**Header search path:**
`"$(HOME)/Library/Developer/GStreamer/iPhone.sdk/GStreamer.framework/Headers"`

And that was it. Build takes long time the first time, but it works.

The other option that worked was to change `File->Workspace Settings->Build system` to `Legacy Build System`, but with the steps above I can use the `New Build system`.

Update: Just installed Xcode Version 10.2 beta 3 (10P99q) and now works, even archive.

Comment: For me all I had to do is replace ~ with $(HOME) in the search paths. Xcode broke ~ for some ungodly reason.

Comment: Update: with Xcode Version 10.2 beta 3 (10P99q) now works, even archive.