# GStreamer Xcode 10.1 gst/gst.h not found

Tags: ios, xcode, gstreamer, xcode10.1

GStreamer gst.h file is not found error is coming in Xcode 10.1. Has anyone been able to find a solution for it???

This error even comes if I use Objective-C as primary language for iOS Project.

Comment: Perhaps have a look here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero/issues/81

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Xcode changed the path setting mechanism. Home dir ~/ not working now, use $(HOME) indeed. Just change the project settings (Project ->TARGETS ->Build Settings)

Change both **Framework Search Paths** & **Header Search Paths** prefix ~/ to $(HOME), after that, it now will be:

Framework Search Paths: `"$(HOME)/Library/Developer/GStreamer/iPhone.sdk"`

Header Search Paths: `"$(HOME)/Library/Developer/GStreamer/iPhone.sdk/GStreamer.framework/Headers"`

Face the same issue just now, after this, all works fine.